# Oracle SQL developer selecting 10 rows

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi quite new to oracle sorry for noob question but i cant find a way to fetch a few rows i am more of a mysql expert :P

```
SELECT * from aa.xxx  
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 
10 ROWS ONLY ;
```

Here is the error in sql developer

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 2 Column: 8

Comment: When you say "fetch a few rows", are you planning to iterate through the rows? If so, you may need to use pl/sql and cursors to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

use Metacolumn `ROWNUM`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT ROWNUM recno, t.* 
     FROM RLFRJ.SP35_V_EMPORIUM  t
     ) 
 WHERE recno BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Comment: Seams ok but doesn't this have performance issue if i have a very large database

Comment: Yes, correct, but OFFESET / FETCH NEXT is also slow then. It´s more importante to apply a good WHERE-predicate in the inner select.

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy is missing

```
SELECT * from aa.xxx
ORDER BY XXXXXXX  
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY ;
```

Comment: please provide me the error it shows, is it still the same error?

Comment: can you provide me the table schema and exact sql query?

Comment: offset results and fetch first clause are Oracle 12c features. So if you are using 12c and higher, this code should work otherwise, you should use the other answer.